# How to check checkbox array values exist from database PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, laravel

I want to check either the countries exist in countries and the checkbox will be displayed. The values is directly from the database. I can't set the value at the input since it is array/multiple values. So, I want to check every array so that it will be a checkbox.

**Controller :**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $region = Region::find($id);
    $countries = Country::all();
    $country_region = DB::table('regions')
        ->select('countries.id', 'countries.name')
        ->join('country_region', 'regions.id', '=', 'country_region.region_id')
        ->join('countries', 'country_region.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->where('regions.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    $items = array(
        'region' => $region,
        'countries' => $countries,
        'country_region' => $country_region,
    );

    return view('admin.region.edit')->with($items);
}
```

**blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Country</label>
    <select id="test" type="checkbox" name="country_id[]">
        @foreach ($countries as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}" selected @if (in_array($item->id, array_keys($country_region))) checked="checked"
            @endif>{{$item->name}}
        </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, I put php statement inside the blade to check either $country_region is exist in the countries or not. I got errors that related to the array such below :

```
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

Database :

Country Region Table :
[image: Country Region Table]

Region Table :

[image: Region Table]

Country Table :
[image: Country Table]

Comment: `$item->id` is an object but you put that on `in_array()` method

Comment: because $item->id also an array inside the $country_region. @Moshiur

Comment: are you trying to make an option selected? then why are you adding checked attribute? it is used in checkbox but you are using it in selectbox

Comment: i used checkbox already before but still not work

Comment: you must add it outside of the selectbox

Comment: @Moshiur Probably wants to use `selected`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need array function there like `in_array` since you are already looping each country, simple if should work, also please show the content of tables you are trying to compare.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Country</label>
    <select id="test" type="checkbox" name="country_id[]">
        @foreach ($countries as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}" selected @if ($item->id == $country_region.country.id) checked="checked"
            @endif>{{$item->name}}
        </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean the content of tables? you mean the database?

Comment: Yes, content of tables like `Country`, `Country_Region`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pluck` instead of `select` in the query.

```
$country_region = DB::table('regions') 
     ->join('country_region', 'regions.id', '=', 'country_region.region_id')
     ->join('countries', 'country_region.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
     ->where('regions.id', '=', $id)
     ->get()
     ->pluck('countries.name', 'countries.id');
```

Comment: why I have to use pluck instead of select?

Comment: You have used **in_array** that is the reason you need an array to compare the value and the **pluck** method returns an array

Answer (score 0):

`$country_region` is not an array in your controller. It's an `Eloquent collection`. To change it to array you simply use `toArray()` on it.

In your controller, replace this:

```
$items = array(
            'region' => $region,
            'countries' => $countries,
            'country_region' => $country_region,
    );
```

with this:

```
$items = array(
            'region' => $region,
            'countries' => $countries,
            'country_region' => $country_region->toArray(),
    );
```

Comment: @asad Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use pluck to get all country's id in an array

```
$country_region = DB::table('regions')
    ->join('country_region', 'regions.id', '=', 'country_region.region_id')
    ->join('countries', 'country_region.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
    ->where('regions.id', '=', $id)
    ->pluck('country_region.id')
    ->toArray();
```

Then don't use `array_keys()` anymore. Modify your HTML like this

```
<option value="{{$item->id}}" selected @if (in_array($item->id, $country_region)) checked="checked"
    @endif>{{$item->name}}
</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure that $country_region is an array

Comment: This statement is more appropriate for comments, not for answers. Please elaborate on it.